# What is the opacity graph in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I am new to Tensorboard.

This is an output I have by this line:

`self.logger.experiment.add_scalars("losses", {"train_loss": loss}, global_step=self.current_epoch)`

[image]

I can only touch the dark blue line, which is probably the loss I logged, but not the light blue line.

- What is the light blue line?
- Why is the dark blue line not strictly continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I asked the same question on Github](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/5316).

> The light one is the actual data, and the bold curve is the smoothed
> curve. Use the slider in the UI to adjust it.